# What is difference between assign ExpandableObjectConverter attribute to Property level or class level?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, typeconverter

Assuming WinForms UserControl class. and there's another property of object ( class Car )

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))] // first approach - class level
public class Car
{
    public int Model{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}



   public class UserControl1: UserControl
   {
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))] // Second approach - property level
     public Car CarProperty{
       get;
     }    
   }
```

What is difference between class level and property level when insert this attribute specially? I see some .NET Libraries for example DevExpress doing it in property level.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter)), DXCategory(CategoryName.Behavior)]
        public LayoutViewField LayoutViewField {
            get { return layoutViewFieldCore; }
            set { AssignLayoutViewField(value); }
        }
```

and .NET standard doing

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FontConverter))]
public sealed class Font : MarshalByRefObject, ICloneable, ISerializable, IDisposable
```

I missed up now what is difference? And which one should we end up..

Comment: The pre-built `ExpandableObjectConverter` can be used both ways. In your example, the Car class (which contains Properties of a known Type) is decorated with this TypeConverter. So the `CarProperty` in your UC doesn't need to specify a `TypeConverter`. What if `Car` doesn't specify a `TypeConverter`? Maybe it's not designed to be used in a `PropertyGrid`. Or, the `Car` class has a Property of Type `SomeOtherClass` that doesn't have a `TypeConverter` and you cannot modify it? To edit its values in the `PropertyGrid`, you can then decorate the Property.

Comment: In case `SomeOtherClass` contains Types that the Framework doesn't know how to handle in this context and `SomeOtherClass` doesn't expose any, then you need to provide a `TypeConverter`, maybe derived from `ExpandableObjectConverter`, that instead *understands* this content and can serialize/deserialize it in a way that the `PropertyGrid` can use to get/set property values of that class and, as a consequence, also update the code in the Designer's file.